# config a listener to execute only in one bundle symfony 2

Tags: symfony

We need to configure a listener to check some registers in a db but we need to do this check action only in one bundle for every actions in it.

We don't want to call a function everytime we write a function in the bundle so we have thought to do a listener.

Does Symfony allow to configure a listener only in one bundle?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you call a service inside a constructor at the top of each class in the bundle?

Comment: You could also set up a normal listener for every page, then at the top of that function wrap an if statement around the database call so it only runs if you are inside that bundle. The overhead of runnning an empty function every time would be so minute it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks @whistlergreg.
I liked the second solution. I am trying to find how to get the bundle name or instance and check it. See the Glen-Swinfield answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about this incorrectly. You can't configure a listener to execute for a bundle. In practice a listener just waits for its event to be fired -it's the event that defines when a listener gets called. What you really want to achieve is to fire an event before each action in your controller(s).

You could do this buy listening for the kernel.Controller event then doing something like this:

```
$controller = $event->getController();
if ($controller instanceof mybundlecontroller) {
    // fire custom event e.g. My.db.lookup
}
$event->setController($controller)
```

You can then have a separate listener that fires in this case.

See docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event

Comment: Thanks @glen, it works ok. I had to logout the session first to see the changes.
But I can't set "mybundlecontroller" to my instance controller name
I try myBundleController, acme\myBundleController, acme\myBundleController\Default, myBundleControllerDefault....
No one works fine :(

Comment: How can I get the instance name from a controller (got from $event->getController() ) ?

Comment: Try var_dump(get_class($controller));

Comment: Hello again @glen!
I got the class but I don't know why it doesn't find the instance in the if condition.
So I change de If condition to:
if(get_class($controller[0])=='acme\myBundle\Controller\DefaultController') 
It works fine. Do you think that this is a good alternative?

Comment: Well, I suppose if it works then it's a good alternative ;), though what you have there is functionally the same as:

`if ($controller[0] instanceof \acme\myBundle\Controller\DefaultController) {...do stuff...}`

(sorry about the late response)

Comment: And what about bundle? Can we have something like if (... instanceof someBundleName()) {} ? Because setup each controller - a lot of monkey code =\

Comment: simple extend all bundle's controllers from some class or interface: `interface Bundle1Controller {}; class MyController imlements Bundle1Controller` and later, in the listener check this: `if($controller instanceof Bundle1Controller) {}` Be care here: `$event->getController()` returns the array usually, use `$controller[0]` if so. :)

Comment: and good explanation in original answer, thanks @GlenSwinfield, I really thinked wrong)

Answer (score 0):

My case... I use event.controller, routes help me to 'use listener for custom routes'

Services

```
    kernel.listener.corporation.manage:
        class:  Site\CorporationBundle\Event\SiteCorporationManageListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Class

```
class SiteCorporationManageListener
{
    private $oEntityManager = null;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $oEntityManager)
    {
        $this->oEntityManager = $oEntityManager;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            // get variable from url if needed
            // $event->getRequest()->get('urlVariable', null); 
            $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');

            if (strstr($route, 'corporation')) {
                if (!strstr($route, 'corporation_index')) {
                    echo 'some request done';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Routes

```
corporation_index_default:
# . . .
corporation_api_default:
# . . .    
corporation_manage_default:
# . . .
```

In our case listener will work only in

```
corporation_api_default:
# . . .
corporation_manage_default:
# . . .
```